# c# javascript mvc - Javascript window.confirm Box set appear after model validation

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have one scenario in my MVC project.

I have model of this, with validation of "Required" for each property as example.

```
public class ResetPasswordViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string NewPassword { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Compare("NewPassword", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.localize), ErrorMessageResourceName = "ErrorMessagePasswordNotMatch")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

I have a HTML form in my View something like this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("register", "account", FormMethod.Post, new { data_ajax = "false", id = "loginForm" }))
{
@Html.ValidationSummary()

<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
    <li data-role="list-divider">@Resources.localize.AccountDetails</li>

    <li data-role="fieldcontain">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)            
    </li>

    <li data-role="fieldcontain">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)            
    </li>

    <li data-role="fieldcontain">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.NewPassword)
        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.NewPassword)
    </li>

    <li data-role="fieldcontain">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
    </li>

    <li data-role="fieldcontain">
        <input data-ajax="false" type="submit" value="Login" />
    </li>
</ul>
}
```

I want to add a window.confirm box when i submit a form by clicking the login button, and I want the window.confirm to trigger only when the form is valid from the model validation.

When i simply set window.confirm on the Login button, it will always trigger first regardless on whether the form is valid.

Would it possible to achieve such that, the window.confirm only appear only after the form is valid? (Without using any jQuery validator)

Comment: Your submitting a form to a controller method so you have left the current page. Where do you expect the 'confirm' to be displayed

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery validate.js in your page like

then use

```
$("input[type='submit']").on("click", function(){  
   var isValid = $("#loginForm").valid();
   if(isValid){
      var isConfirm = confirm("Are you sure you want to proceed?");
      if(!isConfirm){
        return false;
      }
    }
});
```